# "-fobjc-arc" flag doesn't work on octest

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I am sorry that the title could be sort of misleading, but I really don't know how to generalize this issue:

My project(ARCTest) is non-ARC, and I want to add SVProgressHUD into it. I have added the `-fobjc-arc` flag to SVProgressHUD.m.

When I built the project, the `#if !__has_feature(objc_arc)` macro triggered, which means the `-fobjc-arc` flag didn't work. I went to the issue navigator and found that the error occurred at ARCTestTests(Not ARCTest).

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you actually set `-fobjc-arc` in the Compiler Flags on the file?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html

> Can I opt out of ARC for specific files?
>
> Yes.
>
> When you migrate a project to use ARC, the -fobjc-arc compiler flag is set as the default for all Objective-C source files. You can disable ARC for a specific class using the -fno-objc-arc compiler flag for that class. In Xcode, in the target Build Phases tab, open the Compile Sources group to reveal the source file list. Double-click the file for which you want to set the flag, enter -fno-objc-arc in the pop-up panel, then click Done.

[image: How to set -fobjc-arc in Xcode]

You should check the compiler flag in Build message.

```
Compile SVProgressHUD.m ...in /Users/...
```

Click the icon (five horizontal lines in an oval) which is located at the far right end of the line. Then you can see the compile message of the file.

```
CompileC .../SVProgressHUD.o .../SVProgressHUD.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
  cd ...
  export LANG=...
  export PATH=...
  ... -fobjc-arc ...
```

If you can't see `-fobjc-arc` in the compile message, you failed to set the compiler flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the flag to `-fno-objc-arc` instead

Comment: Could you please provide an explanation as to why?

Comment: Oh wow, woops. I read the question backwards. I thought he had an arc project and a non-arc file, not the other way around.